# Change point detection (penalty value)

Tags: change-point

cpmean <- cpt.meanvar(c(rnorm(1000, 10, 5), rnorm(1000, 1, 2), rnorm(1000,5,10)),method='PELT', penalty = 'CROPS', pen.value=c(1,100))
cpmean
ncpts(cpmean) #No of cp

> ncpts(cpmean) #No of cp
> [1] 0

I have no idea why no change points are there.
What values should I set for the pen.value??

Comment: Please do no repost closed questions. You need to fix your questions to meet CV's standards for clarity and being on topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no penalty values because when you set the penalty value to `CROPS` it creates a range of segmentations.  From the `cpt.meanvar` documentation:

> Example of using the CROPS penalty in the above example

`set.seed(1)`

`x=c(rnorm(50,0,1),rnorm(50,5,3),rnorm(50,10,1),rnorm(50,3,10))`

`out=cpt.meanvar(x,pen.value=c(2*log(length(x)),100*log(length(x))),penalty="CROPS",method="PELT")`

`cpts.full(out)`

> returns 6 segmentations for penalty values between 2log(n) and 100log(n).
> We find segmentations with 9, 7, 4, 3, 1 and 0 changepoints.
> Note that the empty final row indicates no changepoints.

`pen.value.full(out)`

> gives associated penalty transition points.  CROPS does not give an optimal set of changepoints thus we may wish to explore further

`plot(out,diagnostic=TRUE)`

> looks like the segmentation with 4 changepoints, 50,100,150,200 is the most appropriate

`plot(out,ncpts=3)`

This indicates that you need to use the `cpts.full()` function in order to view the set of segmentations and you can use the `ncpts` argument in the `plot()` function to plot a specific number.

Comment: Thank you so much, excellent explanation ;)

Comment: @dt_pro: if this answer helped you, please consider upvoting or accepting it, by clicking on the little point-up triangle or the checkmark next to the vote totals, respectively.